# How to calculate IN time and OUT time of moment object in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, time

I have IN time as 09:30 and OUT time as 17:50 and break duration as 01:00.
Now I want the total hours spend in office including break time.
In typescript I have used moment to define these values. These values can be changed by user.
How to calculate time in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) with your requirement. This plugin is build with pipes and I have tried to use the pipes in TS files.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-moment-sample)

I am not sure whether it's straight forward answer but it might help you in your search.

TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DateFormatPipe,DifferencePipe } from 'angular2-moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  startTime : any;
  endTime : any 
  diff : any;

  constructor(){

    this.startTime=new Date().setHours(9,30);
    this.endTime=new Date().setHours(17,50);
    this.diff=(new DifferencePipe()).transform(this.endTime, this.startTime, 'Hours', true);

  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

{{startTime}} : {{endTime}} : {{diff}}
```

Comment: Use split(':') to get hours and minutes. Use parseInt to get the integer, multiply the hours by 60 and subtract. use the % operator to get the minutes result, and Math.floor to get the final hours

Answer (score 0):

issue has been resolved using below code:

```
this.daySettingsForm.totalPresence = moment.duration(
        this.daySettingsForm.departure.diff(this.daySettingsForm.arrival)
      ).format(
```

TimeFormat.SHORT);